# Angular/Breeze - Unable to enter decimal point in an HTML text input

Tags: html, angularjs, breeze

In my HTML markup I have an input of type text which has a two-way binding (using ng-model) to a decimal property. The object which contains this decimal property is fetched using a Breeze query on the client side. I can see that the Breeze query has successfully fetched the data and can see the initial value of the property (i.e. 1.25) in the text input. If I delete the decimal point and try to type it in again it will not allow me to do so and at this point I can only type in a number - effectively what I end up with is an integer value.

Can anyone tell me if Angular or Breeze is doing something behind the scenes that is limiting a text input to only being able to accept numbers instead of any text. I've inspected the input element in question in the browser to see if anything extra was "bolted on" that may have caused this but nothing jumps out. The "fix" or workaround would be change the input type to number and set the step attribute to "any" but nevertheless I would still like to understand the cause so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I had the [same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22296446/1719181), it was breeze that parse the string when the data change, this makes it impossible to get a number after the decimal.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue and I think the problem is that due to the two-way binding the value is expected to be valid at any given moment. Apparently "1." is not a valid number so it doesn't like it. If you type "125" and then go back and insert the "." it will accept "1.25".

My current solution is to use debounced updates:

```html
<input type="{{type}}" ng-model="ngModel" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: { default: 1000, blur: 0 } }">
```

If you do not want timeouts at all you could use just:
ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }

More on this here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your localization settings, the numeric input field may accept only numbers and **commas** (not decimal points). As the validation is done on unser input, angular is able to set the value with the decimal point without failing.

By the way, why would you want to use breeze, when AngularJS has all you need to link your fields to the model?