# Breezejs Double trouble in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, breeze, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to change a value in a angular view from a integer to a float/double value that is bind to ngmodel. The input don’t except anything other than a integer.

My guess is that breeze does something in the background to validate the value or something on the "defined properties". But my knowledge of JavaScript prototyping is very limiting aka I need to learn it..

This is really hard to explain so I created a plunk that can hopefully help: http://plnkr.co/edit/Gcj0VvBE3f8DRbIjMtqt?p=preview

In the plunk I also added a normal object to test the same values and it is working as expected when changing the numbers to floats/doubles.

So the question is why won’t the value changed when binding to a float/double value from breeze?

Comment: Clicking on the Plunkr isn't opening anything for me but what DataType are you using?  An integer can only be a whole number obviously so trying to assign a decimal is illegal.

Comment: I tested the plunk in Chrome, IE11, sorry it is taking a while to load. I am using a double DataType in my model on the server side and when binding to that on the client side it behaves like an integer. When I check the metadata the DataType that breeze assigns is Edm.Double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked a preliminary fix into GitHub for this. Please check it out and let me know if it works ( or not).  We are still testing it.

This issue is caused by Angular's (new) behavior where if the angular digest cycle does not see a change to a model property then it seems to reset the UI to what it was on the previous digest cycle. So.. the idea behind this fix is to convince angular that the model value has changed even when it hasn’t.

and.. nice catch ( this was not obvious and your plunkr helped) :)

> Ward adds: You must love the breeze team responsiveness :-) Jay jumped right on this and came up with an interesting solution. But **please note the word "*preliminary*"** in Jay's answer. We are discussing this "fix" internally and it may be withdrawn. Consider the `zEquivalent` directive  [**in this new plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/E2HgF7ASNWIdwsvzs5G0?p=info) or just wait until the dust settles.

Comment: Yea the breeze team responsiveness is out of this world, when I wake up in South Africa the guys in California delivered! That’s crazy!

Comment: The zFloat directive works great! http://www.breezejs.com/breeze-labs/breezedirectivesfloat

Comment: The problem exists in breeze 1.5.3 and 1.4.11. See http://plnkr.co/edit/R6tMvohfIIYd6Ue9USOz?p=preview (use ...1.5.3/breeze.min.js for 1.5.3).  Although the problem does not exist in the plunker in the orig post.  I assume the version of breeze used in the original post must have a special fix.  When will the released version have the fix?

Answer (score 2):

## Update 12 March

I found what I believe is a better solution for your use case because it does not involve "debouncing" nor any change to Breeze. See the `zEquivalent` directive  [**in this new plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/E2HgF7ASNWIdwsvzs5G0?p=info)

**Reminder**: the "best" resolution of the problem you discovered is still up in the air within the Breeze core team. You should not lock into a particular outcome until we can make a more definitive recommendation.

p.s.: I should have mentioned that Jay and I are on the Breeze core team. We are doing our best to get you out of a jam but sometimes we move a wee too quickly. Bear with us please.

## This answer deprecated as of 12 March

> Leaving it here for "historical" purposes.

I think you should try the `zEquivalent` directive first.

It is important to know that the Angular team is working on a robust extension to data binding that includes "debounce" which is still a good idea for many scenarios. [See this (long) pull request thread](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/2129) on the Angular GitHub site.

#### Original Answer

Consider the `zDebounce` directive currently located [**in this plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/qQGEpn20A22XKwUQWOJo?p=info) which is based on @qorsmond's second attempt.

I'd like to know your thoughts. I'm inclined to call this "the solution" and to add it to Breeze Labs. I'll update this answer when/if I do add it to the labs.

Comment: This really helped me lotz! I was going crazy trying to find a solution as I’m not that familiar with breeze internals but learning as I go. Thanks Ward!

Answer (score 0):

you can use input type="number" step="any" and hide the arrows using css

Comment: I Actually did this, but I want to know why it is behaving like this?

Answer (score 0):

I tracked down the behaviour in the breeze code, when the value change it is intercepted and parsed:

```
var coerceToFloat = function (source, sourceTypeName) {
   if (sourceTypeName === "string") {
        var src = source.trim();
        if (src === "") return null;
         var val = parseFloat(src);
        return isNaN(val) ? source : val;
    }
    return source;
};
```

So when the value change this function is called that parse the string to a float, the problem is as soon as the value entered is some number and a point like `5.` it parse it to the number `5` witch is obviously correct. So you will never be able to get past the point.

When changing the input to a number type it works because its sourceTypeName is not a string.

**Update**

I ended up changing the breeze code to enable the decimal to be entered, I’m still not sure if I missed something but this works for me.

```
var coerceToFloat = function (source, sourceTypeName) {
    if (sourceTypeName === "string") {
        var src = source.trim();
        if (src === "") return null;
        var val;
        if (src.indexOf('.', src.length - 1) !== -1) {
            val = src;
        }
        else {
            val = parseFloat(src);
        }
        return isNaN(val) ? source : val;
    }
    return source;
};
```

Comment: Sorry, I really don't understand your issue.  The code you have above seems wrong in that the purpose of coerceToFloat is to return a number and you will be returning a string. My guess is that your issue is much further upstream and involves incorrect metadata.

Comment: Hi Jay, all I am trying to do is entering a decimal into a input that is bind to breeze entity, please check [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/AzYWB1BTMQBCPA7fsxBG?p=preview) I used the same metadata as the breeze sample.

Comment: I see the problem. Have repro'd the problem. The root cause is that Angular is passing each keystroke into the property, triggering the Breeze parse, and all heck breaks loose from there. We're thinking about what to do. Stay tuned.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work for large or small numbers that might be entered using an exponent form. If I want to enter 2.55e35 (a large salary ;)) the current implementation stops at the 'e'. Is there an easy way to fix this?